# PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_AnyInvokedCount any, when to use it?

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

Just found the [PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::any](http://phpdox.de/demo/PHPUnit/classes/PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase/any.xhtml).

> Returns a matcher that matches when the method it is evaluated for is executed zero or more times.

As far as I know a method is always called "zero or more times", I never called a method -1 or less times. So this matcher should always match. Why does this exist and when to use it?

Comment: besides, it might happen that the class being mocked will have a method named `method`. so using this matcher is the way to stub returns on such method. don't think it's an often thing, still I did have such a case once.

Comment: I can also stub returns without using a matcher. E.g. I use `$someMockObject->method('someMethod')->willReturn('someValue')`

Comment: that's cool ))) but still try to imagine that the class being mocked itself has a method literally named `method`, just as `SomeClass::method` ... to stub the return you have to do `$mock->expects($this->any())->method('method')->willReturn('blah-blah-blah');`

Comment: So it is not possible to use `$mock->method('method')->willReturn('‌​blah-blah-blah');` but I can do `$mock->expects($this->any())->method('method')->willReturn('‌​blah-blah-blah');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small code sample that shows the case of method `::method()`

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function method(){
        // smth is being done here;
    }
}

class SomeClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $mock;

    public function setUp(){
        $this->mock = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')
                           ->getMock();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function canStub(){
        $this->mock->expects($this->any())
                   ->method('method')
                   ->willReturn(true);
        $this->assertTrue($this->mock->method());
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function willCauseFatalError(){
        $this->mock->method('method')
                   ->willReturn(true);
        $this->assertTrue($this->mock->method());
    }
}
```

second test will give `Fatal error: Call to a member function willReturn() on null`.

Even more, if `SomeClass` had any other methods alongside `method`, they would also need to be mocked via `->expects($this->any())...`

Comment: Ok so the difference is that calling `expects` returns an object of type `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker` and on this you can call `method`. Otherwise you would call `method` from your mocked object. This makes sense, even if I did not met the developer that is naming his method `method` up to now ^^

Comment: well, i had such a case once )) it was about deciding what method to call on some service. but a bigger challenge would be mocking method named `expects`

Answer (score 0):

The scenario is basically about a mocked object where the called method is not involved in the test scenario (it could be called one or more times is out of scope for the test case).

As Example:

```
    $entity = $this->getMock(MyEntity::class);

    // Don't worry about how many times this methods is called
    $entity->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getName')
        ->willReturn('Foo');

    $webServices = $this->getMock(ExternalWebServices::class);
    // this call is expensive for the system so I expect that is called only one times 
    $webServices->expects($this->once())
        ->method('expensiveCall');

    $logger = $this->getMock(Logger::class)
        ->expects($this->never())
        ->method('log');

    $myService = myService($logger, $webServices);

    $myService->call($entity);
```

Hope this help

Comment: If the method is not involved in the test scenario, what is the reason for mocking it?

Comment: sorry is not under the test scope (as example only for generate an url or some other stuff)

Answer (score 0):

```
class FooTest {
    public function testSomething() {
        $mock = $this->getMockCollaborator();
        $foo = new Foo($mock, false);
        // make asserts on $foo with "false" state
        // maybe this calls $mock->getName() 4 times
    }
    public function testAnotherSomething() {
        $mock = $this->getMockCollaborator();
        $foo = new Foo($mock, true);
        // make more asserts on $foo with "true" state
        // maybe this calls $mock->getName() 12 times
    }
    protected function getMockCollaborator() {
        $mock = $this->getMock(Collaborator::class);
        $mock->expects($this->any())->method('getType')->willReturn(1);
        $mock->expects($this->any())->method('getName')->willReturn('Test');
        return $mock;
    }
}
```

For any particular test case, you likely know exactly how many times a collaborator's methods *should* be called. However, it is often convenient to share mock collaborators between test cases. When a mock is so shared, it may be more convenient to simply let the methods be called *any number of times* instead of a *particular* number of times.

**Why should one specify the number of times the method is called?**

Three reasons. First, one sets expectations on mocked collaborators to assure the system under test correctly interacts with the collaborator. While wanton verification of call count is probably a [code smell](https://cockneycoder.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/call-counting-when-unit-testing/), verification when the collaborator has side effects is crucial. For example:

- Assuring an event is fired only once
- Assuring a commit is made only once
- Assuring state is queried twice (pre- and post-)
- and others.

Second, so that the isolation framework can fail sooner. This is ideal: the closer a test fails to the buggy code, the better. This "fail fast" rationale was specifically discussed in [the paper that introduced mock objects](https://web.archive.org/web/20050227171220/http://www.connextra.com/aboutUs/mockobjects.pdf):

> On the other hand, a mock implementation can test assertions each time it interacts with domain code and so is more likely to fail at the right time and generate a useful message. This makes it easy to trace the specific cause of the failure, especially as the failure message can also describe the difference between the expected and actual values. For example, in the widget code above, the mock widget knows that it should only be polled once and can fail as soon as a second poll occurs.

Third, in PHPUnit specifically, if the mocked class contains a method called `method`, one must specifically call `expects` prior to calling `method`. Per the [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs):

> If the original class does declare a method named "method" then `$stub->expects($this->any())->method('doSomething')->willReturn('foo');` has to be used.

**What is the difference between specifying `any` and making no specification?**

In PHPUnit, nothing: `any` is a default state of being. Mockery is the same with its [`zeroOrMoreTimes()`](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html) matcher. However, not all isolation frameworks follow this. IIRC, Moq has a default call count expectation of one and must be modified downward if "any" applies.

Comment: And why should one even specify the number of times the method is called? What is the difference if I specify `any` or just nothing at all?